# C#のWebBrowserでkeyupイベントを発生擬似的に発生させる方法がわかりません。

Tags: c#, .net

## 概要

WebBrowserで特定のサイトをクローリングする際、パスワードを入力する要素に対するkeyupイベントの発火を受けて非活性状態のボタンを活性化させて、クリックできるようになるボタンがあります。
このボタンは単にWebBrowser内のボタンのHTMLElementを拾ってInvokeMember("click")しただけでは押せません（次のページへ遷移できません）。
ボタンを押して次のページへ遷移させたいです。

## 詳細

パスワードを入力するinput要素とボタン要素を含むHTMLは次のようなものです。

・パスワードのinput

```
<td>
    <input name="moge" id="moge" type="password" size="11" maxlength="4" autocomplete="off" value=""></input>
</td>
```

・ボタン

```
<li>
    <input name="hoge" id="btn" onclick="return shitanisetsumei()" type="image" src="hoge.png" disabled=""></input>
</li>
```

ボタンにあるshitanisetsumei()はボタンがクリックされていなければtrueを返すボタン連打対策のようです。

サイトをWebBrowserでなく人の手で辿っていくと、パスワードのinput要素のキーを入力する際、キーを押下して離す際にボタンが活性状態になります。

WebBrowserでこのボタンの活性状態を作り（form要素に対してkeyupイベントを発火させる？）、ボタンをクリックしたいのですがその方法がわかりません。

## 動作環境

・.NET Frame Work 4.5  
・Visual Studio2013

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 実際に試してませんがHtmlElement.Enabled で活性化ってできないのですか？

Comment: おっしゃる通り
```HtmlElement.Enabled = true```
した後ボタンクリックで画面遷移できました！ありがとうございます。

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/22631 マルチポスト

Answer (score 2, accepted):

コメントをいただいた通り、

```
HTMLElement button = document.GetElementById("btn");
button.Enabled = true;
button.InvokeMember("click");
```

で解決できました。ありがとうございました。